# How to remove white space over the bootstrap navigation bar in vue js?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

i've just created new component with navbar code within:

```
<template>
  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark static-top">
.....
</template>
```

and my index.html without any changes.

[image]

I've tried to make changes based on my googling results, actually set my own style to nav tag didn't help.

Comment: Did you use Vue Cli? If so, by default it adds a 60px top padding at the end of the `App.vue` file. You just need to remove these styles. Also, when developping web apps, always use your browser's developer tools! The source of this space can easily be found by right clicking on it and "Inspect element"

Comment: @blex yes i used cli, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using VUE CLI then in you App.vue there will be a style block like this

```
<style>
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

because of this `margin-top: 60px` this white space is there. Vue CLI provides this default styling for their default components, you can remove it.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

So use this in App.vue, reasons to set the default for the web base

```
<style>
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
</style>
```